# How do I extend sails.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I would like to extend sailsjs to have something similar to rails strong params
i.e.

req.params.limit(["email", "password", "password_confirmation"])

I have created this already as an add on, but I would like it to automatically attach to the request.params

Addon:

```
limit = function(limiters){
  params = this.all();
  self = Object();
  limiters.forEach(function(limiter){
    if(params[limiter]){
      self[limiter] = params[limiter]
    }
  return self;
}
```

request:

```
req.params.limit = limit;
req.params.limit(["email", "password"]);
```

How would I go about adding this to the framework as a module?

Answer (score 1):

i think you could just create a [policy](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies)

```
// policies/limit.js
limit = function(limiters){
params = this.all();
self = Object();
limiters.forEach(function(limiter){
  if(params[limiter]){
    self[limiter] = params[limiter]
  }
return self;
}

module.exports = function limit (req, res, next) {
  req.params.limit = limit;
  req.params.limit(["email", "password"]);
  next();
};
```

then you can add the policy in your ./config/policies.js file. the example is for all controllers/actions. in the link above is the documentation on how to add it to specific actions.

```
// config/policies.js
module.exports.policies = { 
'*': 'limit'
};
```

EDIT: of course you can do the call to req.params.limit(...); in your controller if you don't want it static in your policy. policies are in general nothing more than express middlewares

Comment: Would the req then get passed to the controller with limit attached to it?

Comment: And thats an interesting idea to scope it in a policy

Comment: yes you can use limit in all controllers affected by the rule set in ./config/policies.js

Answer (score 0):

I see the use cases for this on controller actions, limiting possible searches and so on.

On the other hand: When you just want to your model not to take up undefined attributes found in a create request you could simply set `schema` to true for the corresponding model:

```
// models/example.js

module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {...}
}
```

Setting it globally:

```
// config/models.js

module.exports.models = {
  schema: true,
  ...
}
```