# Is there a way to extend controllers in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Often times I will want to perform some action on every page of my web application or make some method available to all of my controllers. In the past with object oriented MVC frameworks I would have all of my controllers extend a root controller, placing everything I wanted done on every page in the constructor of that root controller. How would I accomplish something similar with sails.js / javascript?

Comment: It looks like this will do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240705/how-do-i-extend-sails-js-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best option is to use a Sails "service" module (`/api/services/MyService.js`). Then you should be able to use it as `MyService.function()` from within your controllers.

See [this GitHub question](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/860) for more details.